# Meteor event helper callback not firing

Tags: meteor

When a `button` is clicked, I expect to get an alert stating the text of the button but the callback isn't getting fired.

I guess, my question could be, how to access the value of text which is in the document being rendered by `#each`, from the collection `footerButtons`

Please help me understand why I failed and how to fix it. Thanks

```
<template name="footer">
 <footer>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {{#each footerButtons}}
        <h2>
          <button class="col-xs-{{footerButtonsScaling}}" type="button">{{text.toUpperCase}}</button>
        </h2>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
Template.footer.events({
  'button': function (event, template) {
    alert(event.target.text.value);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write 'click button'!
And you access the context by using this.